# System.currentTimeMillis() give wrong output android

Tags: android

when i am print `System.currentTimeMillis()`

give me :

```
11-03 14:47:05.400: INFO/System.out(7579): date is :: 14475410111
```

What is the correct procedure to get entire date with time.?

Comment: use new Date(). And u see that System.currentTimeMillis() return long what do u expect from this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get current date and time in Android, You can use:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());
```

### Output:

Current time => Thu Nov 03 15:00:45 GMT+05:30 2011

FYI, once you have this time in 'c' object, you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to get date/time in desired format.

### Final Solution:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Sring formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());     // c is Calendar object
System.out.println("========> formatted date => "+formattedDate);
```

**Output:**
========> formatted date => 2011-11-03 15:13:37

Comment: yes obvious you can do it with SimpleDateFormat class. Try it

Answer (score 3):

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

By the way : `currentTimeMillis()`

> Returns the current system time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes This is the correct way to get the current time and date. afte that you need to convert it  to desired format.

```
public static String getDateFromTimeStamp(String timeStamp){
        return new Date(Long.parseLong(timeStamp)).toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) class.

(What makes you think that's wrong? You're asking for the time in milliseconds.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)